# Ubuntu 20.04 Ping randomly stops and works in one direction

Tags: networking, 20.04, ping

I am facing an odd issue for the past few days. We have a 3 instance Kubernetes setup, all 3 instances are using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The pings were working fine and suddenly stopped working, without any update/installation into the node itself. I wonder if anything changed on the network gateway side, but there is no change on the gateway side as well.

- ufw is disabled

| Node | Ping Status |
| --- | --- |
| Node 51 (master) | Ping works to Node 52, **Ping fails to Node 53** |
| Node 52 (worker) | Ping works to Node 51, Ping works to Node 53 |
| Node 53 (worker) | **Ping works to Node 51**, Ping works to Node 52 |

Node 1 network and route detail

```
default via 172.16.25.1 dev eno1 proto static 
10.244.0.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.0.1 
10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.5.0/24 via 10.244.5.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.16.25.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.25.51 
172.16.25.0/24 via 172.16.25.1 dev eno1 proto static

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.25.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.25.255
        inet6 fe80::b67a:f1ff:fee2:9334  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:7a:f1:e2:93:34  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4175094283  bytes 3583980311063 (3.5 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 154659  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4347655900  bytes 4081889938622 (4.0 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:7a:f1:e2:93:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.25.51/24 brd 172.16.25.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b67a:f1ff:fee2:9334/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.25.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.244.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
10.244.2.0      10.244.2.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
10.244.5.0      10.244.5.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
172.16.25.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
172.16.25.0     172.16.25.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eno1
```

Node 1 iptable entries

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY
-N KUBE-NODEPORTS
-N KUBE-PROXY-CANARY
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check service ports" -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Node 3 network and route detail

```
default via 172.16.25.1 dev eno2 proto static 
10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
10.244.2.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.2.1 
10.244.5.0/24 via 10.244.5.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
172.16.25.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.25.53 
172.16.25.0/24 via 172.16.25.1 dev eno2 proto static

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.25.53  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.25.255
        inet6 fe80::b67a:f1ff:fee2:94f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:7a:f1:e2:94:f1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3211362535  bytes 3081309266071 (3.0 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 121709  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2936433937  bytes 2631825614517 (2.6 TB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:7a:f1:e2:94:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.25.53/24 brd 172.16.25.255 scope global eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b67a:f1ff:fee2:94f1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.25.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno2
10.244.0.0      10.244.0.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
10.244.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
10.244.5.0      10.244.5.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
172.16.25.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
172.16.25.0     172.16.25.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eno2
```

Node 3 iptables entries

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY
-N KUBE-NODEPORTS
-N KUBE-PROXY-CANARY
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check service ports" -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -s 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.244.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

[UPDATE]
Running the `ip neighbor` command shows the correct entries with REACHABLE status.

From Node 1

```
$ ip neigh show | grep 172.16.25.5
172.16.25.52 dev eno1 lladdr b4:7a:f1:e2:8e:24 REACHABLE
172.16.25.53 dev eno1 lladdr b4:7a:f1:e2:94:f1 REACHABLE
```

From Node 3

```
$ ip neigh show | grep 172.16.25.5
172.16.25.52 dev eno2 lladdr b4:7a:f1:e2:8e:24 REACHABLE
172.16.25.51 dev eno2 lladdr b4:7a:f1:e2:8e:24 REACHABLE
```

[UPDATE] After running wireshark

Based on the wireshark scan, Node 53 does receive the ping request and also returns a response. But Node 51 never receives the response.

| Node | Wireshark scan |
| --- | --- |
| Node 51 (master) | Ping goes to Node 53 but the response is missing |
| Node 53 (worker) | Ping received from 51, also returns response |

Comment: I don't know Kubernetes at all, but from what I am seeing you have 2 different IPs configured for the same interface of `flannel.1`.  You can have multiple IPs for one interface but each needs its own designation like `eth0.1` and `eth0.2`

Comment: So I installed tshark and started the ping scans on both. I see that pings are received on node3 and also response sent, but node1 only records the ping request, ping reply entries are missing. I am not a Network expert, so trying to figure out why specifically the reply entries are missing.